# How to trigger change event on checkbox when its value is changed in component angular 7

Tags: angular

I have multiple checkboxes,I am changing checkbox value(with queryPrams) using patchValue.How do I trigger change event?

### .html

`<mat-checkbox formControlName="A (change)="checkboxChanged($event.checked)">A</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox formControlName="B" (change)="checkboxChanged($event.checked)" >B</mat-checkbox>`

### component.ts

```
`this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.myForm.patchValue({'a':params['a']});
      this.myForm.patchValue({'b':params['b']});
```

}`

How to trigger change event after value is updated.

Comment: Hello Jack! [Reading the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue) would tell you that you can pass an `emitEvent` option to the patchValue method!

Comment: I tried emitEvent and it is not working

Comment: why not just call the change event after you patchValue code?